# "comment on" vs. "comment about?"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is one more appropriate than the other, is either ok?

Bonus question: is it ok to end a sentence with either one of these?

For ex.: "Is there anything else you'd like to comment on?" or "...comment about?"

Comment: It is better to comment on this site than answer .This is my comment about your question

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: It is a good question that could use some research about usage.